# SemaphoreSlim(1) how can i know if other threads are waiting

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, semaphore

For synchronization, I have created a SemaphoreSlim(1).
Meaning that if i have single instance of this semaphore in my class as lock:

```
private SemaphoreSlim _initializationSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
private bool _isInitialized = false;    

public void Initialize()
{
  await _initializationSemaphore.WaitAsync();
  if (_isInitialized)
  {
     _logger.Warn("SDK is already initialized");
  }
  //Do some logic only once and only ..
  _isInitialized=true;
  _initializationSemaphore.Release();
}
```

The first thread who enter the function, will continue to run the code, other threads will not be able to enter the function until the first thread has released the semaphore.
My question is - how can i know how many threads are currently stucked in the:

```
await _initializationSemaphore.WaitAsync();
```

Thanks.

Comment: That's forbidden knowledge, whatever number you'd get is unreliable a nanosecond later.  Use a debugger.

Comment: @ilansch: What are you actually trying to do? The point of Hans' comment is that there isn't anything useful you could do with this information.

Answer (score 7):

For something quick and dirty, how about just keeping a static variable that holds the count?

```
private SemaphoreSlim _initializationSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
private bool _isInitialized = false;    
private static int _waitingThreads = 0;    

public void Initialize()
{
  try
  {
      Interlocked.Increment(ref _waitingThreads);
      await _initializationSemaphore.WaitAsync();
  }
  finally
  {
      Interlocked.Decrement(ref _waitingThreads);
  }
  if (_isInitialized)
  {
     _logger.Warn("SDK is already initialized");
  }
  //Do some logic only once and only ..
  _isInitialized=true;
  _initializationSemaphore.Release();
}
```

Comment: thanks for solution.. i was wondering if they have something in .net that can tell me, there are ways to avoid this.. also inherit it and make my own implementation of WaitAsync() that will keep a counter.. If there is no clean way, i guess using sempaphore this way, is not ok :)

Comment: .NET doesn't have anything that tracks the number of callers to a method because it doesn't have to care about it. Certainly trying to write your own WaitAsync is a solution and it just depends on how much you need to get into it.

Comment: yup. anyway thanks for solution. i guess i'll implement my own class later on :)

Comment: If you want to use this, you'll need to synchronize access to `_waitingThreads`. I suggest you use `Interlocked.Increment(ref _waitingThreads);` and `Interlocked.Decrement(ref _waitingThreads);`. Otherwise, two threads entering the `Initialize` method at the same time can result in `_waitingThreads` being incremented only once.